# draw direction cosines using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, angle

How I can easily draw the direction cosines using TikZ?[image]

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far? Consider adding a minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: I draw the vector but I don`t know how I can put the angles

Comment: `\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \tdplotsetcoord{P}{\rvec}{\thetavec}{\phivec}
    \draw[-stealth,color=red] (O) -- (P) node[above right] {$P$};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @alejandromuñoz Have a look at the example in chapter 3.5.1 `tdplotdrawarc` in the `tikz-3dplot`[documentation](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 3D solution via `tikz-3dplot`. Two inputs are required (1) Euclidean coordinate `(\ax,\ay,\az)` and (2) its Euclidean 2-norm/distance `\r`.

The code below basically does the following

1. Draw coordinate systems
2. From input, one gets the P point, then extended to V point via external extention skill.
3. Draw angles from P to 3 axes in the first quadrant, respectively via 
   `tdplot-define-points` command which requires 3 inputs (the origin, P, and a point in axis) to form a triangular polytope
   and then draw the each arc via `tdplot-polytope-arc`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{vector/.style={<-,black,thin}
}
%  ---- draw coordinates
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{0.2}%{0.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{0.3}%{0.3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\az}{0.6}%{0.5}
\def\r{0.7}               %{0.655} %  2-norm of (x,y,z)
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]     
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);  

\draw[thick,->,orange] 
(0,0,0) -- (1.3,0,0)node[anchor=north east]{$\mathbf{V_x}$};   
\draw[thick,->,orange] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.3,0)node[anchor=north west]{$\mathbf{V_y}$}; 
\draw[thick,->,orange] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1.3)node[anchor=south]{$\mathbf{V_z}$};

\draw[thick,->,blue] 
(0,0,0) -- (1,0,0)node[above]{$\mathbf{e_x}$}; 
\draw[thick,->,blue]  (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0)node[below]{$\mathbf{e_y}$}; 
\draw[thick,->,blue]  (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1)node[right]{$\mathbf{e_z}$};   
% ---- start from P to draw angles a, b, c
\coordinate [] (P) at (\ax,\ay,\az){}; 
\draw[-stealth,thick] (P) -- ($(P)!-0.3cm!(O)$) coordinate (V)node[above]{$V$};

{     %define 3 points 0,A,B for angle c
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0,0,\r)(\ax,\ay,\az) 
\draw[fill=cyan](0,0,\r) --(0,0,0)--(\tdplotbx,\tdplotby,\tdplotbz);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[fill=cyan]{\r}{anchor=south}{$c$}
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[vector]{\r}{anchor=south}{$c$}     % draw arc arrow
}
{     %define 3 points 0,A,B for angle a
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(\r,0,0)(\ax,\ay,\az)
\draw[fill=cyan,opacity=0.8](\r,0,0)--(0,0,0)--(\tdplotbx,\tdplotby,\tdplotbz);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[fill=cyan,opacity=0.8]{\r}{anchor=south}{$a$}
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[vector]{\r}{anchor=south}{$a$}     % draw arc arrow
}
{     % define 3 points 0,A,B for angle b
\tdplotdefinepoints(0,0,0)(0,\r,0)(\ax,\ay,\az) 
\draw[fill=cyan](0,\r,0) --(0,0,0)--(\tdplotbx,\tdplotby,\tdplotbz);
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[fill=cyan]{\r}{anchor=west}{$b$}
\tdplotdrawpolytopearc[vector]{\r}{anchor=west}{$b$}      % draw arc arrow
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple 2-D solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\definecolor{corange}{rgb}{0.93, 0.57, 0.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=0.7,inner sep=2pt]
\path coordinate (o) at (0,0)
coordinate (x) at (220:4)node(X) at($(o)!.9!(x)$)[label=below right:$\textcolor{corange}{V_x}\textcolor{blue}{e_x}$]{}
coordinate (y) at (0:6) node(Y)  at($(o)!.9!(y)$)[label=below:$\textcolor{corange}{V_y}\textcolor{blue}{e_y}$]{}
coordinate (z) at (90:6)node(Z)  at($(o)!.9!(z)$)[label=right:$\textcolor{corange}{V_z}\textcolor{blue}{e_z}$]{}
coordinate (v) at (50:5)node at($(o)!1!(v)$)[label=right:$V$]{};

\draw [fill=green,->]($(o)!.42!(y)$)to (o) to($(o)!0.5!(v)$) to [bend left] node[right]{$b$}($(o)!.42!(y)$);
\draw [fill=green,->]($(o)!.37!(z)$)to (o) to($(o)!0.4!(v)$) to [bend right] node[above]{$c$}($(o)!.37!(z)$);
\draw [fill=green,->]($(o)!.3!(x)$)to (o) to($(o)!0.25!(v)$) to [bend right] node[above left]{$a$}($(o)!.3!(x)$);
\draw  (o) edge [->,corange] (x) edge [->,thick,blue] (X)
           edge [->,corange] (y) edge [->,thick,blue] (Y)
           edge [->,corange] (z) edge [->,thick,blue] (Z)
           edge [->,thick] (v); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is like this:

[image]